# @SortableField not working in nested entity

Tags: java, hibernate-search

My code has the class **Credenciada** that inherits from class **Cadastro** that has the atributte(nested class) "cep" of **CEP** type.
The CEP class has the atributte "uf" of **String** type.

The uf atributte was annoted with @SortableField, so the index is save with "cep.uf" name. But when I need sort by "cep.uf" a NullPointerException is throwed, because the Hibernate-search didn't find this index/atributte.

OBS: I saw that attribute "allFieldDescriptors" of class **IndexedTypeDescriptorImpl** didn't have the "cep.uf" ocurrency. Because in line 139 of this method returns null on this point "return allFieldDescriptors.get(fieldName)".

Cadastro.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CAD")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Indexed
public class Cadastro extends Entidade<Long> {
    @Id
    private Long codigo;

    @IndexedEmbedded
    @NotAudited
    @ManyToOne
    private CEP cep;

    //more attrs and getters/setters here
}
```

Credenciada.java:

```
@Entity
@Indexed
@Table(name = "CAD_CRDC")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "CD_CAD_CRDC")
public class Credenciada extends Cadastro {

    //many attrs and getters/setters here

}
```

CEP.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CAD_CEP", schema = "dne")
public class CEP extends Entidade<Long> {

   @Id
   @Field(name = "cep", store = Store.YES)
   private Long nrCep;

   @SortableField
   @Field(store = Store.YES)
   private String uf;

}
```

Search code:

```
FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = hibernateUtil.getFullTextEntityManager();

QueryBuilder qb = HibernateSearchUtil.createQueryBuilder(fullTextEntityManager, Credenciada.class);     

BooleanJunction<?> criterios = qb.bool();

//many conditions here...

org.apache.lucene.search.Query rootQuery = criterios.isEmpty() ? new MatchAllDocsQuery() : criterios.createQuery();

FullTextQuery query = fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(rootQuery, Credenciada.class);

query.setSort(qb.sort().byField("cep.uf").createSort());

List resultList = query.getResultList();
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.search.query.dsl.sort.impl.SortFieldStates.getCurrentSortFieldTypeFromMetamodel(SortFieldStates.java:156)
    at org.hibernate.search.query.dsl.sort.impl.SortFieldStates.determineCurrentSortFieldTypeAutomaticaly(SortFieldStates.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.search.query.dsl.sort.impl.ConnectedSortContext.byField(ConnectedSortContext.java:42)
    at br.gov.sindec.modulos.credenciada.repositorio.impl.CredenciadaRepositorioImpl.criarQueryListarCredenciadasIndexadas(CredenciadaRepositorioImpl.java:124)
    at br.gov.sindec.modulos.credenciada.repositorio.impl.CredenciadaRepositorioImpl.listarCredenciadasIndexadas(CredenciadaRepositorioImpl.java:52)
```

Comment: Which version of Hibernate Search? This is possibly an issue which was already solved.

Comment: The version 5.7.0.CR1, while waiting for 5.7.0.Final version.

Thanks Sanne. I follow your posts in http://in.relation.to/sanne-grinovero/index.html.

Comment: I just confirmed this is a bug. We'll work on it, thanks: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-2587

Comment: Thanks @YoannRodière

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Hibernate Search 5.6.1.Final and 5.7.0.Final have just been released](http://in.relation.to/2017/02/22/hibernate-search-5-7-0-Final/); both versions include a fix for your issue ([HSEARCH-2587](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-2587)).